# Name for class of functions satisfying $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\lambda g(x)/g(\lambda x)>1$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, terminology

I would like to ask whether is used some name for functions $g:A\to\mathbb{R}$, $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, for which $$\exists \lambda>1:\;\; \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\lambda g(x)}{g(\lambda x)}>1.$$

Comment:  What is A ? And RA  ?

Comment: Let just $A=[0,1]$  